# Emscripten Fetch always return 0

Tags: c++, xmlhttprequest, emscripten

I follow the Synchronous Fetch example that comes with Emscripten as follow;

```
void main()
{
      emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
      emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
      strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "GET");
      attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY | EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_SYNCHRONOUS;
      emscripten_fetch_t *fetch = emscripten_fetch(&attr, "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/E9DF/production/_96317895_gettyimages-164067218.jpg");
      printf("Fetch finished with status %d\n", fetch->status);
}
```

It always returns 0 from fetch status

I compile with

```
FLAGS            += -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++ -O3
FLAGS            += -s WASM=1  -s USE_WEBGL2=1 -s FULL_ES3=1 
FLAGS            += -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 
FLAGS            += -o hello.html 
FLAGS            += -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap']"    
FLAGS            += --no-heap-copy
FLAGS            +=  -s FETCH=1
```

However when I test with async and read the data inside OnSuccess function. The data prints correctly

```
static
void ondownload_success(emscripten_fetch_t *fetch)
{
    printf("[ download ][ OK ]    %llu bytes  [ URL ]: %s\n", fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);

    printf("%c %c %c", fetch->data[0], fetch->data[3], fetch->data[2] );
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
}
```

What is the problem with my Fetch sync code? Everything is exactly the same as the "example_synchronous_fetch.cpp" example

I run on Windows10. Emscripten 1.38.29. Using Microsoft Edge to browse the file directly without a server ( double click on hello.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous `fetch` has some extra restrictions and it seems that your build flags don't enable synchronous `fetch`:

> Synchronous Emscripten Fetch operations are subject to a number of
> restrictions, depending on which Emscripten build mode (linker flags)
> is used:
>
> No flags: Only asynchronous Fetch operations are available.
>
> –proxy-to-worker: Synchronous Fetch operations are allowed for fetches that only do an XHR but do not interact with IndexedDB.
>
> -s USE_PTHREADS=1: Synchronous Fetch operations are available on pthreads, but not on the main thread.
>
> –proxy-to-worker + -s USE_PTHREADS=1: Synchronous Fetch operations are available both on the main thread and pthreads.

https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/fetch.html#synchronous-fetches

Comment: This answer seems not works for wasm compile, at least not works on emscripten v2.0.20. Due to synchronous relative code will not be run with WASM=1 https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/2.0.20/system/lib/fetch/emscripten_fetch.cpp#L155

Comment: I get this error msg "error: --proxy-to-worker is not supported with -s USE_PTHREADS>0!"